# making div position fixed causing accordion not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to fixed the position of div containing accordion. However if i fixed the position of div. the accordion stop working.

```
<div>
  <div style='position:fixed;width:100%;z-index: 10000; top: 0; '>
    <div id="main"></div>
  </div>
  <div id='grid' style='z-index: 10030;'></div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function() {
  var staticDiv = "<div class='accordion-container'>    <a  class='accordion-toggle'>Heading 1</a>  <div class='accordion-content'>     Content 1   </div></div><div class='accordion-container'>   <a href='#' class='accordion-toggle'>Heading 2</a>  <div class='accordion-content'>     Content 2   </div></div>"

  jQuery("#main").append(staticDiv);
  jQuery("#main").append(staticDiv);
    $('#grid').css('paddingTop', $('#main').height())

 $('.accordion-toggle').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        // create accordion variables
        var accordion = $(this);
        var accordionContent = accordion.next('.accordion-content');

        // toggle accordion link open class
        accordion.toggleClass("open");
        // toggle accordion content
        accordionContent.slideToggle(250);

    });

  $("#grid").jsGrid({
    width: "100%",
    height: "400px",
    filtering: true,
    editing: true,
    sorting: true,
    paging: true,
    data: friends,
    fields: [{
        name: "Name",
        type: "text",
        width: 100
      }, {
        name: "Age",
        type: "number",
        width: 50
      },
      countries, {
        name: "Cool",
        type: "checkbox",
        width: 40,
        title: "Is Cool",
        sorting: false
      }, {
        type: "control"
      }
    ]
  })
})
```

here is the link to [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maqsoodgul/s1hjy147/1/).
according to [jquery forum](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-have-accordion-with-position-fixed), i must wrap the accordion in other div and make that fixed position but somehow it is not working in my case

Comment: Why do you have to fix an accordion?

Comment: @YATO i want to display  the data of accordion all the time even when the width of grid increase and the user scroll it.

Comment: Why its getting down vote??

Comment: This is to clarify. You want your accordion's content to be visible when the page loads?

Answer (score 0):

You right in wrapping your accordion in another div. You should not be fixing the position of the accordion itself. Instead, add those attributes to the div you used to wrap your accordion.

```
<div style='position:fixed;width:100%;z-index: 10000; top: 0;'>
  <div >
    <div id="main"></div>
  </div>
  <div id='grid' style='z-index: 10030;'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: the problem with this is that it will fixed the grid and if the width of grid is greater the the remaining column are hidden

Comment: The question calls for a solution that fixes an accordion that does not work when it is in fixed position. You have not specified the requirement hence I came up with this answer. Please consider updating the question or open a new question.